# Spring Data REST - how to create an object with relationships in one request?

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "distributor")
class Distributor : AbstractEntity<Long>() {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    val name: String? = null

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "distributor", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @RestResource
    var managers: MutableList<DistributionManager>? = null

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "distributor")
    var catalog: MutableList<Good> = mutableListOf()
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "distribution_manager")
class DistributionManager : AbstractPersonEntity<Long>() {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "distributor_id")
    var distributor: Distributor? = null
}
```

What request i need do for creating 'Distributor' entity with relationship 'DistributionManager' in one request?

So far I have found a way to do this in 3 requests:

- Create a 'Distributor'
- Create a 'DistributionManager'
- Create a relation

But it's kind of cumbersome

Comment: what do you mean by one request?
One DB call?

Comment: I mean one http request.
The information from the documentation provides a way through 3 requests
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships

Comment: if you really want to have finegrained control on REST API's., you should not use spring-data-rest.
Better write your controllers and api's yourself.

Comment: I recently got acquainted with Spring Data REST and studied its documentation. This is a great solution, not only because it shortens the code, but also because it provides a lot of things. The only thing that confuses me is that I haven't found a way to create an entity with a relation for 1 request.
I already know what Spring MVC is, my goal is to study this practice just to get away from the usual controllers